# Props is not passing in child component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react. I am trying to pass props to the component. However, it seems like the props are not received correctly by the child.

My App Class is like,

```
import React from 'react'
import ImageList from './ImageList'


class App extends React.Component{
    state = { images: [] }

    render = () => {
        return(
            <div className="ui container">
                <ImageList images={this.state.images}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

And my ImageList Class is like

```
import React from 'react'

class ImageList extends React.Component{
    render = (props) => {
        console.log(props)
        return(
            <div>
                test
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ImageList
```

As you can see I am passing `<ImageList images={this.state.images}/>` from App. This should pass the images state which is an empty array right now. However, `console.log(props)` of ImageList is showing `undefined` but I expect to see an empty array somewhere there(props.images).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a class component, `render` doesn't take a props argument. You reference it with `this.props` instead.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I will accept the answer. One little query. I don't need render = (props) => anymore then. (props) portion is unnecessary.  Right?

Comment: The (props) portion is unnecessary, yes.

Answer (score 2):

In a class component, render doesn't take a props argument. You can try to access props like this in the class component.

```
import React from 'react'

class ImageList extends React.Component{
    render () {
        console.log(this.props)
        return(
            <div>
                test
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ImageList
```